# Peoplesoft Integration broker Received fatal alert: protocol_version

Tags: weblogic, peoplecode

I am trying to consume third party rest service. When I send Get request the services should return json with link that I would open and transfer the user.
The things that I've done so far:

- created request and response documents
- created messages
- created webservice that generates the correct URI
- added the certs in digital storage and in keystorage on the web server
- encrypted the secureFileKeystorePasswd
- added JavaVM Options=-Dxdo.ConfigFile=%PS_HOME%/appserv/xdo.cfg -Xms32m -Xmx128m -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2  in appserv and prcsserv
- added -Dweblogic.security.SSL.protocolVersion=TLS1.2  with setEnv.cmd
- created custom node with implicit SSLProtocols with TLS1.2. When I ping the node it works fine if the header with the TLS1.2 is missing it doesn’t work.

When I invoke %IntBroker.SyncRequest(&msg); this is the error I get:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1979)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1086)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at psft.pt8.pshttp.https.HttpsClient.doConnect(HttpsClient.java:246)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.openServer(NetworkClient.java:136)
    at psft.pt8.pshttp.https.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
    at psft.pt8.pshttp.https.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:350)
    at psft.pt8.pshttp.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:76)
    at psft.pt8.pshttp.https.HttpsClient.newClient(HttpsClient.java:132)
    at psft.pt8.pshttp.https.HttpsClient.newClient(HttpsClient.java:100)
    at psft.pt8.pshttp.https.HttpsURLConnection.connect(HttpsURLConnection.java:468)
    at psft.pt8.pshttp.PSHttp.getResponseCode(PSHttp.java:378)
    at com.peoplesoft.pt.integrationgateway.targetconnector.HttpTargetConnector.send(HttpTargetConnector.java:843)
    at com.peoplesoft.pt.integrationgateway.service.BasicConnectorInvocator.execute(BasicConnectorInvocator.java:131)
    at com.peoplesoft.pt.integrationgateway.framework.GatewayManager.invokeService(GatewayManager.java:148)
    at com.peoplesoft.pt.integrationgateway.framework.GatewayManager.connect(GatewayManager.java:192)
    at com.peoplesoft.pt.integrationgateway.listeningconnector.PeopleSoftListeningConnector.doPost(PeopleSoftListeningConnector.java:186)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751)
    at com.peoplesoft.pt.integrationgateway.listeningconnector.PeopleSoftListeningConnector.service(PeopleSoftListeningConnector.java:87)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at com.peoplesoft.pt.integrationgateway.common.IBFilter.doFilter(IBFilter.java:84)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found what was the problem for me. I needed to configure the generated routing in the service I made for protocol TLSv1.2.